# numpy arbitrary precision linear algebra

Tags: python, math, numpy, linear-algebra, arbitrary-precision

I have a numpy 2d array [medium/large sized - say 500x500]. I want to find the eigenvalues of the element-wise exponent of it. The problem is that some of the values are quite negative (-800,-1000, etc), and their exponents underflow (meaning they are so close to zero, so that numpy treats them as zero). Is there anyway to use arbitrary precision in numpy?

The way I dream it:

```
import numpy as np

np.set_precision('arbitrary') # <--- Missing part
a = np.array([[-800.21,-600.00],[-600.00,-1000.48]])
ex = np.exp(a)  ## Currently warns about underflow
eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(ex)
```

I have searched for a solution with gmpy and mpmath to no avail. Any idea will be welcome.

Comment: I'd be looking for a solution that doesn't involve exponentiation

Comment: @David Heffernan Well, that is the physical problem I'm solving. I could not find any way to do the diagonalization before the exponents.

Comment: If you were taking the matrix exponential, this would be a much easier problem. Then, you'd be able to do exp(eigenvalues). Since you have to do the element wise exponential though, this is a completely different ball game.

Comment: Care to elaborate more? Your statement `ex = np.exp(a)` seems to be out context, because `eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(a)` gives perfectly reasonable answer. But `ex` should be treated as a 2x2 matrix, where all elements are equal to zero. Thanks

Comment: @eat, you're right, the mistake was with the `eig(a)`, should have been `eig(ex)`

Comment: Now, what would you expect the eigenvalues and -vectors of a matrix of only zero elements to be? Thanks

Comment: Rescale your problem? For almost all practical proposes exp(-1000.) is zero.

Comment: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf has 19 different way to compute the matrix exp.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SymPy can calculate arbitrary precision:

```
from sympy import exp, N, S
from sympy.matrices import Matrix

data = [[S("-800.21"),S("-600.00")],[S("-600.00"),S("-1000.48")]]
m = Matrix(data)
ex = m.applyfunc(exp).applyfunc(lambda x:N(x, 100))
vecs = ex.eigenvects()
print vecs[0][0] # eigen value
print vecs[1][0] # eigen value
print vecs[0][2] # eigen vect
print vecs[1][2] # eigen vect
```

output:

```
-2.650396553004310816338679447269582701529092549943247237903254759946483528035516341807463648841185335e-261
2.650396553004310816338679447269582701529092549943247237903254759946483528035516341807466621962539464e-261
[[-0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999994391176386872]
[                                                                                                      1]]
[[1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000560882361313]
[                                                                                                    1]]
```

you can change 100 in N(x, 100) to other precision, but, as I tried 1000, the calculation of eigen vect failed.

Comment: By the way, SymPy uses mpmath for its arbitrary precision floating point numbers.

Comment: SymPy is the place to go for many mathematical problems. Meanwhile, if you need arbitrary precision `int`-s, which don't overflow on simple matrix multiplications when having a dozen digits - you can use `dtype=object`. Of course - this won't help OP, who is dealing with arbitrary precision `float`-s.

Answer (score 15):

On 64-bit systems, there's a `numpy.float128` dtype.  (I believe there's a `float96` dtype on 32-bit systems, as well)  While `numpy.linalg.eig` doesn't support 128-bit floats, `scipy.linalg.eig` (sort of) does.

However, *none of this is going to matter*, in the long run. Any general solver for an eigenvalue problem is going to be iterative, rather than exact, so you're not gaining anything by keeping the extra precision!  `np.linalg.eig` works for any shape, but never returns an *exact* solution.

If you're always solving 2x2 matrices, it's trivial to write your own solver that should be more exact. I'll show an example of this at the end...

Regardless, forging ahead into pointlessly precise memory containers:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.linalg

a = np.array([[-800.21,-600.00],[-600.00,-1000.48]], dtype=np.float128)
ex = np.exp(a)
print ex

eigvals, eigvecs = sp.linalg.eig(ex)

# And to test...
check1 = ex.dot(eigvecs[:,0])
check2 = eigvals[0] * eigvecs[:,0]
print 'Checking accuracy..'
print check1, check2
print (check1 - check2).dot(check1 - check2), '<-- Should be zero'
```

However, you'll notice that what you get is identical to just doing `np.linalg.eig(ex.astype(np.float64)`. In fact, I'm fairly sure that's what `scipy` is doing, while `numpy` raises an error rather than doing it silently. I could be quite wrong, though...

If you don't want to use scipy, one workaround is to rescale things after the exponentiation but before solving for the eigenvalues, cast them as "normal" floats, solve for the eigenvalues, and then recast things as float128's afterwards and rescale.

E.g.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-800.21,-600.00],[-600.00,-1000.48]], dtype=np.float128)
ex = np.exp(a)
factor = 1e300
ex_rescaled = (ex * factor).astype(np.float64)

eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(ex_rescaled)
eigvals = eigvals.astype(np.float128) / factor

# And to test...
check1 = ex.dot(eigvecs[:,0])
check2 = eigvals[0] * eigvecs[:,0]
print 'Checking accuracy..'
print check1, check2
print (check1 - check2).dot(check1 - check2), '<-- Should be zero'
```

Finally, if you're only solving 2x2 or 3x3 matrices, you can write your own solver, which *will* return an exact value for those shapes of matrices.

```
import numpy as np

def quadratic(a,b,c):
    sqrt_part = np.lib.scimath.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)
    root1 = (-b + sqrt_part) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b - sqrt_part) / (2 * a)
    return root1, root2

def eigvals(matrix_2x2):
    vals = np.zeros(2, dtype=matrix_2x2.dtype)
    a,b,c,d = matrix_2x2.flatten()
    vals[:] = quadratic(1.0, -(a+d), (a*d-b*c))
    return vals

def eigvecs(matrix_2x2, vals):
    a,b,c,d = matrix_2x2.flatten()
    vecs = np.zeros_like(matrix_2x2)
    if (b == 0.0) and (c == 0.0):
        vecs[0,0], vecs[1,1] = 1.0, 1.0
    elif c != 0.0:
        vecs[0,:] = vals - d
        vecs[1,:] = c
    elif b != 0:
        vecs[0,:] = b
        vecs[1,:] = vals - a
    return vecs

def eig_2x2(matrix_2x2):
    vals = eigvals(matrix_2x2)
    vecs = eigvecs(matrix_2x2, vals)
    return vals, vecs

a = np.array([[-800.21,-600.00],[-600.00,-1000.48]], dtype=np.float128)
ex = np.exp(a)
eigvals, eigvecs =  eig_2x2(ex) 

# And to test...
check1 = ex.dot(eigvecs[:,0])
check2 = eigvals[0] * eigvecs[:,0]
print 'Checking accuracy..'
print check1, check2
print (check1 - check2).dot(check1 - check2), '<-- Should be zero'
```

This one returns a truly exact solution, but will only work for 2x2 matrices. It's the only solution that actually benefits from the extra precision, however!

Comment: I think you also need a special treatment for `c != 0 and b != 0` to determine the correct eigenvalues or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, numpy does not support higher than double precision (float64), which is the default if not specified.

Try using this: http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/

List of features (among others)

Arithmetic:

- Real and complex numbers with arbitrary precision
- Unlimited exponent sizes / magnitudes

Comment: That is certainly the most interesting answer so far, but I could not find a eigenvalue solver in mpmath. Do you know if it includes one, or do I have to construct it myself?

Comment: Yes, I did not find it either. I don't think numpy itself can help you here, either combined with mpmath or bc (Spike's answer), so you would need to work around it to get your result. You can take a look at numpy source to see what linalg.eig() looks like. It might be not too hard to implement in your program.

Comment: There is a `numpy.float128` for what it's worth. I don't think it's supported by `numpy.linalg`, but it is for basic operations.

Comment: @milancurcic - For what it's worth `numpy.linalg.eig` calls LAPACK routines. (Which is why `numpy.linalg` doesn't support 128-bit precision). Regardless, looking `numpy.linalg.eig`'s source is unlikely to help you implement a basic eigenvalue solver.

Comment: @Joe Kington - is it the newer version of numpy (1.6.*) that has numpy.float128? The version I have (1.5.1) does not have such dtype.

Comment: @milancurcic - No, numpy has had `float128` for a _very_ long time (at least since 1.1, and I'm pretty sure it was there a long time before that).  However, it's only present on a 64-bit system.  Otherwise, I think there's a `float96` on 32-bit systems? I could be quite wrong about the `float96` part, though...

Answer (score -3):

So you need 350 digits of precision. You will not get that with IEEE floating point numbers (what numpy is using). You can get it with the bc program:

```
$ bc -l
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
scale=350
e(-800)
.<hundreds of zeros>00366
```

Answer (score -4):

I have no experience with numpy in particular, but adding a decimal point with a set amount of zeros may help. For example, use 1.0000 instead of 1. In normal python scripts where I've had this problem, this has helped, so unless your issue is caused by an oddity in numpy and has nothing to do with python, this should help.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Sinthet, but that does not solve the problem. The numbers are already floats, it's just that exp(-800) is about 3.7E-348, which is less then numpy's (or python's) precision