# Precision of numpy's eigenvaluesh

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, linear-algebra

First I find the eigenvalues of a (4000x4000) matrix by using [`numpy.linalg.eigvalsh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvalsh.html). Then, I change the boundary conditions, expecting only a minor change in the eigenvalues.

Subtracting the eigenvalues is vulnerable to floating point errors, so I've used some relative tolerance.

Now say I have a eigenvalue `A = 1.0001e-10`, and another `B = 1.0050e-10`. According to my humble knowledge of floating-point arithmetic, `A - B != 0`. The problem is, that these numbers come from linear algebra calculations involving many orders of magnitude. Other eigenvalues might for example be of order `1`.

The question is, what is the precision of eigenvalues calculated using `numpy.linalg.eigvalsh`? Is this precision relative to the value (`A * eps`), or is it relative to the largest eigenvalue? or perhaps relative to elements of the original matrix?

For example, this matrix:

```
1      1e-20
1e-20  3
```

gives the same eigenvalues as this:

```
1     1e-5
1e-5  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if Lapack is used underneath eigvalsh, but this might be of interest:

Lapack error bounds for the Symmetric/Unsymmetric eigenproblem:

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node89.html

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node91.html

Comment: Thanks, @aka.nice that seems like the right direction. Am I right in understanding that precision goes like epsilon times the largest eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, in symmetric case that's what I understand too.

Comment: Let me add that usually in rank computation eigenvalues less than N times epsilon times the largest eigenvalue are considered equal to zero. (All computations in magnitude).

Answer (score 0):

First, the solver is not exact. Second, your example matrices are poorly conditioned: the diagonal elements are orders of magnitude larger than the off-diagonal ones. This is always going to cause numerical issues.

From simple algebra, the determinant of the second matrix is `(1 * 3) - (1e5 * 1e5) = 3 - 1e-10`. You can already see that the precision problem is actually twice as large the precision of your smallest element. (The same applies for the eigenvalues.) Even though linalg is using double precision, because the solver is approximate you get the same answer. If you change the small values to `1e-3` you start seeing a difference, because now the precision is on the order of the numerical approximation.

This specific problem [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876377/numpy-arbitrary-precision-linear-algebra). You can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879889/1580351) how to use sympy to solve the eigenvalues with arbitrary precision.

Comment: Thanks @tiago. The matrices were just examples, to exaggerate the issue at hand, not what I actually use. The question is not about why the results are different, or how to fix that. The question is what is the validity regime of the eigenvalue results, since I want to compare two sets with minor differences. You answered something completely different.

Comment: @jarondl, on a second look I did miss the last paragraph of your question... I thought you were more after arbitrary precision linear algebra.