# unsupported operand in pandas dataframe operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame. I would like to get single value from a column based on a condition involving two another column. I am looking for the value from the column3 for which is the biggest distance in the column1 and 2.

I build the simple example which works:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[.1,3,11.3],'c2':[3,6,.6],'c3':[8,.8,10.9]})
print'data d=\n%s\n' % d                                               
x = float(d.c3[abs(d.c1-d.c2)==max(abs(d.c1-d.c2))].values)
print 'the value of x= \n%s\n' % x
```

The output from this example is as I expect:

```
     c1   c2    c3
0   0.1  3.0   8.0
1   3.0  6.0   0.8
2  11.3  0.6  10.9

the value of x= 
10.9
```

I try to apply exactly the same logic to my original problem with large dataframe inside a class. The code is:

```
yInit = float(self.DenFrame.Depth[abs(self.DenFrame.Hper-self.DenFrame.Vper)==max(abs(self.DenFrame.Hper-self.DenFrame.Vper))].values)
```

but this code produce an error:

```
...
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.9.0-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\series.py", line 73, in wrapper
return Series(na_op(self.values, other.values),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.9.0-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\series.py", line 59, in na_op
result[mask] = op(x[mask], y[mask])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408122/unsupported-operand-types-for-numpy-ndarray-and-numpy-float64) that there could be a problem with type of the columns but Depth is type `numpy.float64` Hper is type `float` Vper is type `float` so I understand how it can apply to my problem.

I don't know from this point what to do as I understand the same code works in one case but not in another and I cannot spot the problem.

Comment: To confirm, `DenFrame.Hper.dtype` and `DenFrame.Vper.dtype` are float64?

Comment: when I use: `print self.DenFrame.Hper.dtype` the output is `object`. For the `print type(self.DenFrame.Hper)` the output is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` all position inside are `float` (I am bit lost with this types)

Comment: What about `DenFrame.Vper.dtype`, also what is the output of `DenFrame.Hper.map(type).unique()` (and same for `Vper`).

Comment: For `print self.DenFrame.Hper.map(type).unique()` the output is: `[<type 'float'> <type 'str'>]` Exactly the same applies to `DenFrame.Vper`

Comment: Unfortunately this means you have some strings in these columns!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have some strings in your `DenFrame.Hper` and `DenFrame.Vper`.

You can see this by checking the `dtype` or type of each element:

```
In [11]: df.Hper.dtype
Out[11]: dtype('object')
```

Means that the numpy array could contain various types, we can see what these types are:

```
In [12]: DenFrame.Hper.map(type).unique()
Out[12]: [<type 'float'> <type 'str'>]
```

And you could inspect which entries are strings:

```
DenFrame[DenFrame.Hper.map(type) == str]
```

Perhaps it makes sense to only include those which are floats:

```
DenFrame_floats = DenFrame[(DenFrame.Hper.map(type) == float) & 
                           (DenFrame.Vper.map(type) == float)]
```

or you could (if it's possible) convert them to floats:

```
DenFrame.Hper = DenFrame.Hper.apply(float)
```