# Precisely multiplying 100,000 decimal digits using decimal module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I am going to calculate values of pi very precisely using python 3.
For that, I first need a precise value of **426880*(10005)^0.5**
now, using

```
>>> from decimal import *

>>> getcontext().prec = 100000

>>> Decimal(10005).sqrt()
```

i got the value of root of 10005
precisely upto 100,000 digits.
But, when i try to multiply this by 426880 using:

```
>>> from decimal import *

>>> getcontext().prec = 1000000

>>> Decimal(426880) * Decimal(x)
```

x being the root of 10005 precisely calculated to 100,000 digits
i only get a 28 digit number instead of the specified precision. 
How to multiply these values precisely?

Comment: Why do you create a new Decimal object for x in the last expression?

Comment: I think sympy has arbitrary precision: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876377/numpy-arbitrary-precision-linear-algebra#answer-6879889

Comment: You code works well in my try.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. show what you are really doing.

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning experience, or do you just need a really precise value of pi?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are either saving x in a string and re-interpreting in or you have x from a previous calculation as a `Decimal` and you are doing `Decimal(A_Decimal)`.  If x is already a decimal then do not reinterpret it and if to save time you are saving if then use `pickle` or `cpickle` to save it as an object.  BTW try to avoid `import *` - use namespaces.

BTW be sure and set the current precision **before** importing x from anywhere!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that when you do

```
 >>> Decimal(426880) * Decimal(x)
```

It's interpreted by Python as

```
>>> Decimal(426880) * Decimal(float(x))
```

When you first declare `x`, Try to make sure it's declared as a `Decimal` and not a `float`ing point number.
I maybe horribly wrong, but I think you should check your code to try and see if you might have done that.