# Basic math operation for vectors of Decimal in Python

Tags: python, decimal

I am searching for a fast implementation to multiply two vectors of decimal in Python. I tried to make two lists and then multiply them:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 20
import cProfile

a = [Decimal(x) for x in range(1,10000)]
b = [Decimal(x) for x in range(1,10000)]
def multiply(a,b):
    [x*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
cProfile.run('multiply(a,b)')
```

and this takes around `0.224` seconds. However, if I try to do the same for numpy vectors:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,10000)
b = np.arange(1,10000)
def multiply(a,b):
    a*b
cProfile.run('multiply(a,b)')
```

It takes `0.000` second. Is there any alternative way to make a vector of decimal and multiply them in python?

Comment: What's the problem with numpy? Numpy was made to do exactly these things very fast.

Comment: `Decimal` is slow. You aren't getting around that.

Comment: The reason NumPy is fast is fundamentally incompatible with decimal.Decimal, which is arbitrary-precision.

Comment: I need a similar package with the same feature of `Decimal` that be comparable with `numpy`

Comment: That's badly formulated and contradicts the valid points already mentioned when you are asking for performance (do you think the decimal package is slow on purpose?).

Comment: It is not on purpose for sure, but I want to multiply two vector of numbers which are super low and NumPy sees them as a sequence of zeros.

Comment: How about scaling super low numbers to high numbers and them scaling them back down?

Comment: Good suggestion, but for my case, the numbers are ranging between 10^-1000 to 1. So there is not a uniform scaling.

Comment: That range is really unfavorable. You need to find a way to change it and that depends on what you're doing. Otherwise, you are forced to use data structures with arbitrary precision and all of them are slow (slower than their counterparts).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy arbitrary precision linear algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876377/numpy-arbitrary-precision-linear-algebra)

Comment: Work with logarithms.