# Use numpy to calculate the inverse of a matrix but got a wrong answer

Tags: python, numpy

I creat a 8 by 8 matrix and want to calculate its inverse.
But the output is strange

```
import numpy as np
a=np.mat([
 [538084012500000.0, 6832812857142.857, 88573500000.0, 1180980000.0, 16402500.0, 243000.0, 4050.0, 90.0],
 [47829690000000, 531441000000, 5904900000, 65610000, 729000, 8100, 90, 1,],
 [13348388671875, 177978515625, 2373046875, 31640625, 421875, 5625, 75, 1,],
 [2799360000000, 46656000000, 777600000, 12960000, 216000, 3600, 60, 1,],
 [373669453125, 8303765625, 184528125, 4100625, 91125, 2025, 45, 1],
 [21870000000, 729000000, 24300000, 810000, 27000, 900, 30,1 ],
 [170859375, 11390625, 759375, 50625, 3375, 225, 15, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
print(np.linalg.det(a))
print(np.linalg.det(a)*np.linalg.det(a.I))
print(a*a.I)
```

**Output:**

[image: Output snapshot]

**Error message:**

```
det(a) is not equal to 0,so a is invertible.\
but det(a)\*det(a.I) is not equal to one.\
and a\*a.I is not identity matrix.
```

Comment: Is it possible that involved numbers are too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy uses double, its accuracy is on the order of 16. The difference between the highest and lowest number in your matrix is of the order of 16. An error in the calculation of the order of 1 is pretty reasonable - It is just what the machine accuracy promises.

Maybe try to use another library that promises bigger accuracy, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876377/numpy-arbitrary-precision-linear-algebra) for a similar problem